# Assign different color ramps by category in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset with similar structure to the simulated bellow:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=runif(1000,-10,10),y=runif(1000,-10,10))
```

I created a columns to inform the quadrants in which X and Y are higher/lower than zero:

```
dat$cond <- NA
dat$cond[which(dat$x>0 & dat$y>0)] <- "HH"
dat$cond[which(dat$x>0 & dat$y<0)] <- "HL"
dat$cond[which(dat$x<0 & dat$y<0)] <- "LL"
dat$cond[which(dat$x<0 & dat$y>0)] <- "LH"
```

I plotted this data to get different colors for each quadrant:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, color=cond)) +
geom_point(size=2, show.legend = FALSE) +
theme_classic() +
theme(text = element_text(colour="black", size = 26), aspect.ratio=1) + 
geom_hline(yintercept=0,color="gray20",linetype=2) +
geom_vline(xintercept=0,color="gray20",linetype=2) + 
scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue", "orange","green"))
```

I need to have this same set of colors but with gradients ranging from white closer to zero to dark color apart from zero.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a bit of a workaround solution but you can use the alpha aesthetic with some custom index to achieve the effect you are describing. Here is a brief example (you can tweak the index generating function to affect the alpha):

```r
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(x = runif(1000, -10, 10), y = runif(1000, -10, 10))

dat$cond <- NA
dat$cond[which(dat$x > 0 & dat$y > 0)] <- "HH"
dat$cond[which(dat$x > 0 & dat$y < 0)] <- "HL"
dat$cond[which(dat$x < 0 & dat$y < 0)] <- "LL"
dat$cond[which(dat$x < 0 & dat$y > 0)] <- "LH"
dat$alpha_idx <- (abs(dat$x) + abs(dat$y))/2

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, color = cond)) +
  geom_point(aes(alpha = alpha_idx), size = 2, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "gray20", linetype = 2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, color = "gray20", linetype = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "orange", "green")) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(text = element_text(colour = "black", size = 26), aspect.ratio = 1)
```

[image]